# Cordova media plugin issue multiple audios

Tags: cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I'm developing an app with angularJS and Cordova

Now I'm using the Media Plugin for play different audios

I detected and issue on iOs when I'm playing a background audio (long audio and looped) and another audio(short and plays only one time), when the second audio is finished, then my background audio also stops

any idea how to fix?

piece of code

```
backgroundMusic = new Media("background",
        function () {
            //success (object has completed the current play, record, or stop)
        },
        function (err) {
            //error
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        },
        function (status) {

            if(status == Media.MEDIA_STOPPED){
                //patch for ios issue
                backgroundMusic.seekTo(1);
                backgroundMusic._position = 0;
                //end of patch
                backgroundMusic.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false});
            }
        }
    );
backgroundMusic.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false});
//and the other audio
openPopUp = new Media("openPopUp.mp3",
        function () {
            //success (object has completed the current play, record, or stop)
        },
        function (err) {
            //error
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );

openPopUp.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false});
```

When the openPopUp audio is finished, then the background audio ends too

Comment: Are you trying to play multiple Audio streams at the same time? I don't think you can do that with the Media Plugin. I've had better experience using this plugin: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

Comment: @johnborges Yes I'am trying to play two audios, the background audio, and some times when user iteracts clicking some items another audio is playing,
For use that plugin, nativeAudio I have to install the Angular service module?
Thanks

Comment: @johnborges It seems that is an error from Cordova media plugin, I found that:
issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7599 
issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11026

Answer (score 1):

a [PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/pull/100) has been made for this problem: "Fix CDVSound killing all audio when a single file finishes".

I test it and it fixes the issue. As Apache has no yet merge the PR, I had to [fork the repo](https://github.com/damienleroux/cordova-plugin-media), include the fix and publish my own version. If you want to try it, replace the original cordova plugin  with:

`cordova add cordova-plugin-media-with-fix@5.0.1-dev-updated-with-fix-2`